# a quesition about c++ file I/O and fstream

Tags: c++, visual-c++, fstream

I need to open a file and get the first character.If I open the file with ios::in,it will not create a file when the file doesn't exist.So when it was failed to open the file, i open the file with `ios::out`, it will creat a empty file, so i can input '0' to the file.

```
fstream passengerData;
passengerData.open("passenger.txt",ios::in);
if (!passengerData)
{
    passengerData.open("passenger.txt",ios::out);
    passengerData << '0' ; 
    passengerData.close();
}
```

When i run this in `visual studio 2015`,it can work well.But in `visual c++ 6.0`, it can only creat a empty file,the '0' is not input into the file.I want to know why the result is different and how to solve the problem.
I also want to know how the bitwise operator OR perform when i use `ios::in|ios::out` or `ios::in|ios::out|ios::app`.

Comment: Visual C++ 6.0 is very outdated. Why are you using it?

Comment: Probably, vc++6.0 does not support reopen same fstream after first attempt failed.

Comment: @MicroVirus my teacher asked us to do our homework with vc++6.0。i need to hand in a vc++ project

Comment: @VladimirGamalian Good call. I see from [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_fstream/open) that it's only since C++11 that `open` also `clear()`s the flags, so maybe you can manually clear the flags before `open` and then it'll work.

Comment: Your teacher must be a dinosaur 0.o

Comment: @zychai Do you check error codes, does the file open for output? Visual studio have had bad cases of incompatibility with the standard, they might have have fixed something (or less probably break) since then. Also check default standard version used by 2015. The stanard behaviour might have changed.

Comment: @MicroVirus in chinese universities，vc++6.0 is popular

Comment: @luk32 thank you ，i will try it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the documentation of [`fstream::open` on cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_fstream/open) it seems that it's only since C++11 that open also `clear()`s the flags on success, so maybe if you manually clear the flags before you call `open` the call will also succeed in VC++6:

```
fstream passengerData;
passengerData.open("passenger.txt",ios::in);
if (!passengerData)
{
    passengerData.clear();
    passengerData.open("passenger.txt",ios::out);
    passengerData << '0' ; 
    passengerData.close();
}
```

Also, you need to check the state of `passengerData` after the second call to `open` as well.

Answer (score 0):

The hunch that MicroVirus took on was right.  I'd like to explain in detail why exactly nothing happened.

Basically, when `passengerData.open("passenger.txt",ios::in);` the `failbit` was set. Now you did retry with `passengerData.open("passenger.txt",ios::out);` which did succeed (sic!), although the error bits were not cleared (pre-c++11 behaviour), and made the subsequent `operator<<` do nothing.

I guess this was a flaw in the standard, and vc++6 is too old for c++11.

[cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/) sources explaing the behaviour:

You use [`operator<<`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/operator_ltlt), which is a [`FormattedOutputFunction`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/FormattedOutputFunction) which says:

> A FormattedOutputFunction is a stream output function that performs the following:
>
> - Constructs an object of type basic_ostream::sentry with automatic storage duration, which performs the following:
>
>   - if `eofbit` or `badbit` are set on the output stream, sets the `failbit` as well [...]

So it checks whether the stream (`passengerData`) is operable. Now, interestingly enough, neither of `eof` or `bad` bits are set, so it seems like a wrong way, however the next step:

> - Checks the status of the sentry by calling sentry::operator bool(), which is equivalent to [`basic_ios::good`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/good).

Which takes you those `eof-`, `fail-`, and `bad-` bits. Those are [`iostate`s](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/iostate). In the *failbit* section you can find:

> The failbit is set by the following standard library functions:
>
> - The constructors of std::basic_fstream, std::basic_ifstream, and std::basic_ofstream that takes a filename argument, if the file cannot be opened.
> - basic_fstream::open, basic_ifstream::open, and basic_ofstream::open if the file cannot be opened.

You can confirm this by checking the `iostate` bits after 2nd open:

```
fstream passengerData;
passengerData.open("passenger.txt",ios::in);
if (!passengerData)
{
    passengerData.open("passenger.txt",ios::out);
    if (passengerData.rdstate() & std::ios_base::fail) {
       std::cout << "stream has failbit set\n";
    }
    passengerData << '0' ; 
    passengerData.close();
}
```